# Single Word Request : Flittering around a shop without buying anything?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there any one word that refers specifically to roaming around a shop, looking and stuff and so on without buying anything ?

I wish to use it in the context of a person fingering the items a roadside stall possesses to stall answering a question.

While the most likely term to be offered would be Window - Shopping, I wish for a word that has a more old - world feeling where the person is toying with the objects, more or less out 0of boredom.

If no word is precisely available, could you kindly provide me with etymologies allowing the creation of a new, pseudo - word ?

Comment: In BrE we'd call this ***browsing***.

Comment: ***To browse***: to ​look through a ​book or ​magazine without ​reading everything, or to ​walk around a ​shop ​looking at several things without ​intending to ​buy any of them. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/browse - Figurative extension to "peruse" (books) is 1870s, American English. http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=browse

Comment: In US, the standard answer to the Q: *Can I help you?* is *Just looking.*

Comment: [Showrooming](http://www.retaildoc.com/blog/amazon-showrooming-brick-and-mortar-retail-store-susceptible).

Comment: If you called it _butterflying_, I think hearers/readers would immediately understand what you meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to "**peruse**" is like "to browse" but more "touchy", which might suit your purposes.  It tends to be used with things that one would read such as magazines or books but can be used with other items too.  It's a sort of cross between "browse" and "examine".  http://www.dictionary.com/browse/peruse?s=t

Comment: Thank you, but as far as I know “ **peruse** “ is in its strictest sense strictly examining an object ? 

I would rather a lighter term – so to speak.

Comment: Yes, *peruse* suggests to me (and it is borne out by OD Online), a more detailed examination than mere browsing. But this seems to make it less suitable for what the OP is describing - looking round a shop.

Comment: It is a form of examination, yes.  You said "fingering", which suggests the person is picking things up: are they picking things up without looking at them?

Comment: @MaxWilliams The individual referenced such **is** picking up things, rummaging through them and so on without actually caring about the contents.                                                        

So, contextually, their picking up stuff may be in a manner such that they are not actually looking at the objects picked up. May I know why if their was a specific reason this question was asked by you ?

Comment: Just that if they *are* looking at the things they pick up then that makes "peruse" a better choice.  If they're not looking at the things then peruse isn't right.

Answer (score 2):

Peruse, browse, look around... window shopping is another term, though it implies you're not physically going into the store.  Definition from [Google, browse](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=browse)

> *browse* - to survey goods for sale in a leisurely
>   and casual way: he stopped to browse around a sporting goods store.

Comment: I added the source of, and the link to, your definition.  The site requires quotations to be referenced and be linked (if they can).

Answer (score 1):

The correct phrase would be [*window shopping*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/window-shopping)

> the activity of spending time looking at the goods on sale in shop windows without intending to buy any of them

---

Another more informal phrase would be [*shop hopping*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=shop%20hopping):

[ warning - Urban Dictionary reference ]

> To go from store to store in search of great prices and good products